# Loop over a custom tag with a parameter that returns a query

Tags: django, django-templates

My custom tag is:

```
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def last_three_messages(request):
    u=User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    last_three_messages=Message.objects.filter(to_user=u, opened=False)[:3]
    return last_three_messages
```

How can I loop over this in the template?
I tried:

```
{% for message in last_three_messages request %}
    do something
{% endfor %}
```

This returned an error:

> 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for message in
>   last_three_messages request

How can I loop through the queryset and pass request as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't called the tag; just referring to the name inside a for tag wouldn't call it.

You would need to call it first and assign its result to a variable:

```
{% last_three_messages request as my_messages %}
{% for message in my_messages %}
```

but a much better approach would be to write this as a filter:

```
@register.filter
def last_three_messages(request):
    ...
```

and call it as

```
{% for message in request|last_three_messages %}
```